# Import Excel spread sheet into Access

Tags: excel, python-2.7, ms-access-2010

What is the code sintax to import an excel file to an MS access database IN PYTHON ?
I have already tried making it a text file but with no sucesss

Comment: No. Should I ? i have been trying to find the right syntax because im not sure it can even be done. could please give an exmaple

Answer (score 1):

I just tested the following and it successfully imported data from an Excel document named "xlData.xlsx" and created an Access 2010 table named [fromExcel]

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pypyodbc
cnxn = pypyodbc.connect(
    r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};' +
    r'DBQ=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb')
crsr = cnxn.cursor()
crsr.execute(
    r"SELECT * INTO fromExcel " +
    r"FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;ACCDB=YES;DATABASE=C:\Users\Public\xlData.xlsx].[Sheet1$]")
crsr.commit()
crsr.close()
cnxn.close()
```

Comment: when i run this i get the error :import pypyodbc
ImportError: No module named pypyodbc

Comment: I went through the website downloaded the module and ran it. i still get the same error. im running python 2.7.3

Answer (score 0):

In Access select "External Data" then under "Import & Link" select Excel. You should be able to just use the wizard to choose the Excel file and import the data to a new table.

Comment: I wanted to do it in python. I will edit my question to reflect that

Comment: Ah, I didn't get that from the question. Afraid i can't help then.